# React POST DATA TO object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react, JavaScript. Code is written in JavaScript.

I want to fetch data to post but it gives me null.

After passing object data to the API I get this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

For Example

Comment: I think you should make your question more descriptive. There is too little information written here

Comment: how to I send the data to Api after making input to post it in the api and I have different type of data

Comment: You might need to show some code for clarity.It is absolutely okay to hide sensitive information. It's hard to tell what language you are using and the kind of error you are getting. Also the pictures doesn't clarify the fetched data and the response from the posted data. The more the info (non-sensitive) you give, the better you get help

Comment: I'm using react ,  javascript    // this the code    <div className="form-group" >
                        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handelInputChange} className="form-control" id="name" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group" >
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.handelInputChange} className="form-control" id="email" />
                    </div>

Comment: when I handlesubmit I executed the input to send it as Json file but when I send the data it show as null except for the data that for example const data ={.  data_not_null : this.state.name,  data_null ={this.state.name} }

Comment: const data = {
            data_not_null: this.state.name,
            data_null ={
                name: this.state.name
            },
            email: this.state.email };